# Should I store a Birthday or other date that should not change with TimeZones in CoreData as Date or String

Tags: ios, swiftui, dateformatter

I have several dates that I want to store in CoreData.  Those dates will always be fixed regardless of timezone and the time component is never needed.  So that when the date is fetched and displayed using formatter as a string it should always display the exact same date and not jump to another date depending on the device time zone.

A birthday might be one example of this.  Presently I am capturing the users input from a DatePicker and storing that Date value in CoreData in a field with type Date.  However occasionally the day (eg. 14 Feb 1999) is off by one day.

Is it better to store this as a String?  Or should I be parsing the Date differently to display.  Currently I am using the following code to get the date and save it:

```
@State var birthdate: Date = Date()
...
DatePicker("Birthdate", selection: $birthdate, displayedComponents: .date)
    .datePickerStyle(.compact)
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
```

and to save it:

```
let newUser = User(context: viewContext)
...
newUser.birthdate = birthdate

do {
    try viewContext.save()
} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

And later after retrieving I'm using the following formatter to display it:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
```

Comment: Yes, a string in a known format would be better for your purposes. Or even better, multiple numbers representing month and day etc.

Comment: Note: in swift a `Date` is `A specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone.`, doc at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date . So storing a `Date` is independent of any time zone

Comment: kind of.  It does contain time zone information so when you select a Date from a picker at 0100 AM Hong Kong Time on the 14th of February that time when retrieved with a device on New York time will show 1300 PM on the 13th of February.  So if I store my birthday on in Hong Kong and then retrieve it later in New York it will appear as the 13th instead of 14th depending on what time I saved it.  That's the problem I'm having.

Comment: **No**,`Date` does not contain the time zone, only the way you want to display it does, using some format that includes the time zone you set it to be. You can use the `UTC` time zone for zero longitude, or the Hong Kong one, or the New York one, or any time zone you choose. You can store the date as a string that includes a time zone, or you can store where (time zone)  you were born as well as the `Date`.

Comment: It is as you say a point in time.  The reference is UTC which is a time zone.  The print out of date is: 2019-02-28 01:26:00 +0000 with the +0000 being the timezone as far as I'm aware.